# Escaping the @" " characters in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I'm trying to set the background image of a view based on a passed "artistID." Here is my code so far:

```
 NSString *backgroundImageName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"artistbackground%i.png",_artistID];


    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:backgroundImageName]];
    NSLog(@"%@",backgroundImageName);
```

unfortunately, for the parameter in ImageNamed, I'm passing in:
 artistibackground1

instead of:

@"artistbackgound1"

Any ideas on how to escape the @ and the quotes??

Thanks!!

Comment: Hunh? To create a `UIImage` from the `imageNamed` method, you simply need a string that contains *just the filename*. The `@""` syntax is simply a special syntax that allows you to easily create NSStrings directly (without calling `[[NSString alloc] init...]`). You're having other problems if the code above isn't working; you don't need to create the `@""` within a second string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",backgroundImageName]];
```

Essentially make two strings, it will add the @"" in the second.

Comment: I'll give you the check. but I found this worked: self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@\"%@\"",backgroundImageName]]];

Comment: however, the image still doesn't load even tho the string is now correct. Any ideas why?

Comment: if the file is named file.jpg this code should work imageName:@"file.jpg" Also, make sure your capital letter are right, it won't work without exact text.

Answer (score 0):

You should use \ before the character you want. An example:

```
NSLog(@"\@\"Try\"");
```

The code prints

```
@"Try"
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget that even string constants are NSString objects in Objective-C. This is part of the magic! I frequently see programmers new to the language writing this line:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",backgroundImageName];
```

But you can simplify this line to:

```
[@"@" stringByAppendingString:backgroundImageName];
```

Magic!